# Read integer from string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a string in form `"blah-blah..obj_xx..blah-blah"` where `xx` are digits. E.g. the string may be `"root75/obj_43.dat"`.

I want to read `"xx"` (or `43` from the sample above) as an integer. How do I do it?

I tried to find "obj_" first:

```
std::string::size_type const cpos = name.find("obj_");
assert(std::string::npos != cpos);
```

but what's next?

Comment: Is `xx` guaranteed to be only two characters? Or can it be any number of characters?

Comment: @Cyber Let's assume it is always 2 chars long.

Comment: I would match string with [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) and then use `std::atoi` on the result.

Comment: What about using a [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) to parse the string, and extract the number part? Otherwise a simple [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My GCC doesn't support regexes fully, but I think this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::string input ("blah-blah..obj_42..blah-blah");
  std::regex expr ("obj_([0-9]+)");

  std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), expr);
  std::smatch match = *i;
  int number = std::stoi(match.str());
  std::cout << number << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With something this simple you can do

```
auto b = name.find_first_of("0123456789", cpos);
auto e = name.find_first_not_of("0123456789", b);
if (b != std::string::npos)
{
    auto digits = name.substr(b, e);
    int n = std::stoi(digits);
}
else
{
    // Error handling
}
```

For anything more complicated I would use regex.

Comment: `e` is always going to be the same as `b`. Also, you can't validate `b` against `npos` *after* you already used it in a way that requires it to be valid.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Copy and paste error. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Still haven't  fixed the validation of `b` after its use.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Nothing wrong with using std::string::npos to find e. It is valid. Hence we can wait with the validation.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right. I got confused by the way the standard formulates this.

Comment: Anyway, more to the point, this fails with the example input given. Instead of 43, it'd yield 75.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, I overlooked that. Substitute cpos for the second parameter in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  const std::string test("root75/obj_43.dat");
  int number;
  // validate input:
  const auto index = test.find("obj_");
  if(index != std::string::npos)
  {
    number = std::stoi(test.substr(index+4));
    std::cout << "number: " << number << ".\n";
  }
  else
    std::cout << "Input validation failed.\n";
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85975150e70d1d0f). Includes (very) basic input validation (e.g. it will fail if the string contains multiple `obj_`), variable length numbers at the end, or even more stuff following it (adjust the `substr` call accordingly) and you can add a second argument to [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to make sure it didn't fail for some reason.

Comment: Disgracefully fragile and ugly.

Comment: It does not handle the `blah-blah`.

Comment: @JBL Updated to be more resilient and less ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option

```
//your code:
std::string::size_type const cpos = name.find("obj_");
assert(std::string::npos != cpos);

//my code starts here:
int n;
std::stringstream sin(name.substr(cpos+4));
sin>>n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirt simple method, though probably pretty inefficient, and doesn't take advantage of the STL:

(Note that I didn't try to compile this)

```
unsigned GetFileNumber(std::string &s)
{
    const std::string extension = ".dat";

    /// get starting position - first character to the left of the file extension
    /// in a real implementation, you'd want to verify that the string actually contains
    /// the correct extension.
    int i = (int)(s.size() - extension.size() - 1);

    unsigned sum = 0;

    int tensMultiplier = 1;

    while (i >= 0)
    {
        /// get the integer value of this digit - subtract (int)'0' rather than
        /// using the ASCII code of `0` directly for clarity. Optimizer converts
        /// it to a literal immediate at compile time, anyway.
        int digit = s[i] - (int)'0';

        /// if this is a valid numeric character
        if (digit >= 0 && digit <= 9)
        {
            /// add the digit's value, adjusted for it's place within the numeric
            /// substring, to the accumulator
            sum += digit * tensMultiplier;

            /// set the tens place multiplier for the next digit to the left.
            tensMultiplier *= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        i--;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

If you need it as a string, just append the found digits to a result string rather than accumulating their values in `sum`.

This also assumes that `.dat` is the last part of your string. If not, I'd start at the end, count left until you find a numeric character, and then start the above loop. This is nice because it's `O(n)`, but may not be as clear as the regex or find approaches.